# Композиция объекта. Паттерны...

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Нужна помощь\подсказка.
Абстрагируемся, приведу аналогию. Если вы хотите читать дальше - убедитесь что поели.

Есть `обед` (Наш объект). Состоит из трех разных вещей. `Первое, второе и третье` (это разные объекты). Нужно создать объект, у которого набор этих вещей разный. Т.е. обед может состоять из первого и третьего, и нет второго. Или только из первого. Или только из третьего, или из всех сразу. Нужно, чтобы обед состоял не более чем из этих трех объектов (первое, второе и третье).
Разум подсказывает, что должен быть паттерн, который мне поможет. Хотелось бы узнать, в какую сторону копать, на что обратить внимание? Ибо переопределять конструктор как-то неразумно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один ответ вам уже дали, попробую привести некоторую логическую альтернативу.

Во-первых, "Первое", "Второе" или "Третье" - слишком слабый признак, чтобы пользоваться для этого наследованием *(иначе любое добавление "Десерта" или абстрактного "Четвертого" блюда)* приведет **к необходимости создавать новый базовый объект**. Таким образом, это - *свойство конкретного объекта*.

Дальше дизайн программы выстраивается следующим образом *(вообще, говоря, имя продукта можно тоже сделать свойством и избежать наследования вообще, но здесь, вероятно, пример будет лучше смотреться с наследованием, нежели без него):*

```
public abstract class Portion {
    // Технические детали можете додумать самостоятельно :)
    public PortionType getType() { ... }
}

// Реализуем так, что тип данной порции = "Первое"
public class Cheesburger : public Portion { ... }

// Реализуем так, что тип данной порции = "Десерт"
public class CocaCola : public Portion { ... }
```

---

Теперь обдумаем, как нам представить себе "Обед". "Обед" - это некоторая коллекция порций, организованная следующим образом, чтобы выполнялись заданные условия *(в вашем случае - состоит **ровно** из трех блюд известных типов)*.

```
public class Meal {
    public List<Portion> getPortions() { ... }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как допустить создание **тех и только тех** обедов, которые удовлетворяют изложенным вами условиям. Решение тоже несложно - запрещаем конструирование объекта `Meal` через его конструктор, и привносим для этих целей некоторую [**абстрактную фабрику.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Возможный интерфейс может выглядеть так:

```
public class MealFactory {
    // Построим, например, по методу 'first fit'.
    public Meal buildFirstFitMealFromAvailablePortions(List<Portion> availablePortions) throws ImpossibleToBuildMealException { ... }

    // А здесь передадим как параметр некоторое правило построения обедов.
    public Meal buildMealFromAvailablePortions(List<Portion> availablePortion, MealBuildingRule buildingRule) throws ImpossibleToBuildMealException { ... }
}
```

Здесь тоже есть варианты - можно стратегии привязать напрямую к билдеру или вообще воспользоваться некоторым методом [**dependency injection.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

---

*Кстати говоря, как альтернативу фабрике вполне **можно рассмотреть паттерн `Builder`,** хорошо рассмотренный в книге [**Effective Java.**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)*

Answer (score 1):

Как-то ты все сам для себя сложно закрутил. У нас есть `ОБЕД` (1 объект), у нас есть 3 `БЛЮДА` (3 разных объекта), осталось создать список `МЕНЮ`, которое будет содержать набор этих этих блюд и класс, который будет следить за логикой (формированием списка).

Comment: Вероятно, аналогия у меня получилась не самая лучшая. Эти три блюда никак не связаны друг с другом (если не считать, что из них состоит объект).

Answer (score 1):

поставленную задачу можно решить таким образом :

```
  class Meal
  {
     public enum Type
     {
        FIRST , SECOND , DESERT
     };

     private final HashMap < Type, Portion > portions = new HashMap < Type, Portion > ();

     public Portion getPortion ( final Meal.Type type )
     {
        return portions.get ( type );
     }

     public List < Portion > getPortions ()
     {
        return new ArrayList < Portion > ( portions.values () );
     }

     public boolean setPortion ( final Portion p )
     {
        if ( ( null == p ) || ( null == p.getType () ) )
        {
           return false;
        }

        // check if exist
        if ( portions.containsKey ( p.getType () ) )
        {
           // uncomment if you don't need replace existing portions
           // return false;
        }

        // store portion by type
        // (override if it already exist)
        portions.put ( p.getType (), p );

        return true;
     }
  }

  class Portion
  {
     private final Meal.Type type = null;

     public Meal.Type getType ()
     {
        return type;
     }
  }
```

а что касается паттернов, если у вас возникают трудности я бы посоветовал не пытатся освоить все сразу, лучше по очереди. 
дело в том что некоторые паттерны являются комплексными и включают в себя несколько других. бывает что примеры кода для нескольких паттернов одинаковые или очень похожие. что сильно затрудняет восприятие :)